# How to find time difference between current array result and next array result using PHP

Tags: php, sql, time

How to find time differencce beween current array result and next array result using PHP? I am using the following program to get result but this helps to subtract with the current values which gives the result as zero.

```
$resultss = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM potentiometer_sensor order by S_No desc limit 0,10");

while($rowss = mysql_fetch_array($resultss))
  {

$time1 = $rowss['2'];

$time2 = $rowss['2'];


echo "t1: ".$t1=strtotime($time1); 
echo "<br/>t2: ".$t2=strtotime($time2);    

echo "<br/>end:".$end=strtotime($time1); 
echo  "<br/>floor value:";  



var_dump (floor(((($end- $t1)/60)/60))/60);     

$Hours = floor(((($end- $t1)/60)/60)/60);    

echo   "<b>".$Hours.' </b>Hours ';

}
```

Comment: `$time1` and `$time2` have same value (`$rowss['2']`)? Also `$end` == `$t1` so `$end - $t1 == 0` is logic

Comment: $rowss['2'] are same as considering this will bring the next value of the array $end=time1 and $t2=time2

Comment: Try to print the values `$time1 $time2 $rowss['2'] $t1 $t2 $end` to check the output.

Comment: I tried both are giving the same value. I wan the next array value. the question is raised to get the rowss1 value and rowss 2 value